# Android 11 Package Visibilty Https

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

Hi upgrading to Android 11 and following this guidance
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-11-package-visibility/

However I dont understand the following query.What is this https scheme actually means?
Is it to allow to make https calls?
Suggestions?

```
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Also is there a link of all of the queries and what they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom `URL Scheme` in Android is an in-page jump protocol, which can also be called `URLRouter`. It opens an Activity through a route similar to opening a web page, rather than directly jumping through an explicit Intent.

The URL Scheme method is to configure the activity in the manifest that can accept the Scheme mode to start. When a call is needed, the URI of the Scheme protocol is added to the Intent in the form of Data, and the activity is called implicitly.

You could read it at [Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer clear now